# How can I set the rpc user credentials in Insight to connect to a custom node?

Tags: json-rpc, bitcore, bitpay, insight-api

Bitpay has done brilliant work in creating the bitcore libraries pack.

I am stuck trying to find the file in which we can add the rpc user name and password for connecting to a custom node inside the insight-api.

here is the code for the insight-api https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api